# Stop sidebar resizing based on text length

Tags: css, bootstrap-5

I'm using bootstrap 5. I'm just started playing with it and from version 4 to 5 there are some big differences.

Here's a jsfiddle to show my [issue](https://jsfiddle.net/70bx4hsg/1/).

The problem is with the `lorem ipsum` text, if that text, be it paragraph, alert, anything, goes over a certain length, it pushes the sidebar with to the left instead of moving the text down in the card it resides.

For example, using just a small text length

```
<div class="alert alert-info m-2">
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry
</div>
```

will show the correct sidebar width.

I'm super confused why it does that. I don't want the sidebar to resize itself based on text length, that feels stupid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And of course you find the solution yourself after asking ... sigh

```
.main-sidebar {
    flex-basis: var(--main-sidebar-width);
    flex-grow: 0;
    flex-shrink: 0;
}
```